# Error message with unboxed closures

Tags: rust

This small FizzBuzz program using unboxed closures gives a rather mysterious error message.

```
fn fizzbuzz<F: Fn(i64) -> bool>(n: i64, f: F, fs: &str, b: F, bs: &str) {
    for i in range(1i64, n+1) {
        match (f(i), b(i)) {
            (true, true) => println!("{:3}: {}{}", i, fs, bs),
            (true, _)    => println!("{:3}: {}", i, fs),
            (_, true)    => println!("{:3}: {}", i, bs),
            _            => (),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    fizzbuzz(30,
             |&: i: i64| { i % 3 == 0 }, "fizz",
             |&: j: i64| { j % 5 == 0 }, "buzz");
}
```

Error message:

```
<anon>:15:14: 15:40 error: mismatched types: expected `closure[<anon>:14:14: 14:40]`, found `closure[<anon>:15:14: 15:40]` (expected closure, found a different closure)
<anon>:15              |&: j: i64| { j % 5 == 0 }, "buzz");
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

Could someone describe the error please?  Thanks.

Comment: Please include all details necessary to answer your question (i.e. the code) in the question body itself. Questions should not depend on an external link, because they tend to break in the long term, and we're trying to build a long-term resource. Cheers.

Comment: Please include the relevant (and only the relevant) code and the error message directly in your question, rather than asking people to click on potentially untrustworthy links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This piece of code demonstrates the essence of the problem:

```
fn show_both<S: Show>(x: S, y: S) {
    println!("{} {}", x, y);
}
```

You can only call it with both arguments *of the same type*, i.e. this is allowed:

```
let x: i32 = 10;
let y: i32 = 20;
show_both(x, y);
```

But this is not:

```
let x: i32 = 10;
let y: f64 = 20.0;
show_both(x, y);
```

This is fairly natural: you specified that *both of the parameters* must be of the same type, even though this type can be arbitrary as long as it implements `Show`.

You have essentially the same thing in your code:

```
fn fizzbuzz<F: Fn(i64) -> bool>(n: i64, f: F, fs: &str, b: F, bs: &str)
```

You declared that both `f` and `b` must have *the same type*. However, for each unboxed closure the compiler generates a *different* type - this is quite natural as well, given that different closures can capture different variables.

You need to specify different type parameters in order to be able to pass different closures:

```
fn fizzbuzz<F1, F2>(n: i64, f: F1, fs: &str, b: F2, bs: &str)
    where F1: Fn(i64) -> bool,
          F2: Fn(i64) -> bool
```

Answer (score 4):

Each unboxed closure definition creates a completely different type. This makes each of the closures defined in `main` a different type. Your `fizzbuz` function, on the other hand, requires each of the closures passed to it to be the same type, `F`. If you change `fizzbuzz`'s signature to:

```
fn fizzbuzz<F: Fn(i64) -> bool, G: Fn(i64) -> bool>(n: i64, f: F, fs: &str, b: G, bs: &str)
```

your code will typecheck.

Basically, the `<F: Fn(i64) -> bool>` syntax doesn't create a wildcard for types that implement the trait parameter (`Fn(i64) -> bool`), but declares a single type which must satisfy the trait parameter and be the same type everywhere it is used. Unboxed closure definitions must be different types both because the may wrap different environments but also because they dispatch to different functions (that is, each has a different body). As a result, `fizzbuzz` needs two different type parameters to accommodate the two closure types.