# Types of unboxed closures being unique to each

Tags: rust

This is in the context of the question at [Error message with unboxed closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867765/error-message-with-unboxed-closures).  The answers point out that Rust generates a type each that is unique to each closure, since each of them can potentially capture a different set of variables from the enclosing scope(s).

Here is my question.  The two different closure types in that FizzBuzz example are labelled differently, but look identical.  How does the compiler resolve the closure type differences while still looking at the identical signatures of the type parameters?

This gap between what the compiler sees and what the programmer sees is confusing.

Thanks.

Edit: By the way, Rust Reference document Section 8.1.10 does not yet say anything about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Again, I want to start with the same example as in that answer. Compare this:

```
fn show_both_1<S: Show>(x: S, y: S) {
    println!("{:?} {:?}", x, y);
}
```

and this:

```
fn show_both_2<S1: Show, S2: Show>(x: S1, y: S2) {
    println!("{:?} {:?}", x, y);
}
```

(now using `{:?}` instead of `{}` because of the recent changes)

The first function requires that *both arguments must have the same type*, even though this type can be arbitrary as long as it implements `Show`:

```
show_both_1::<i32>(1i32, 2i32);      // ok
show_both_1::<f64>(1.0f64, 2.0f64);  // ok
show_both_1::<???>(1i32, 2.0f64);    // not ok!
```

Obviously the last function call does not make sense, because types of the arguments are different, but the function wants them to have the same type. You can't even write the type parameter explicitly - should it be `i32` or `f64`?

The second function allows different types, so all of these calls are ok:

```
show_both_2::<i32, i32>(1, 2);
show_both_2::<f64, f64>(1.0, 2.0);
show_both_2::<i32, f64>(1, 2.0);
```

Now for each argument a different type parameter is used, so it is perfectly fine to pass values of different types, as long as both of these types implement `Show`.

Absolutely the same thing happens with closures. For each closure the compiler generates *a new unique type* which implements one of `Fn*` traits. These types are anonymous, so you can't name them:

```
let f: ??? = |&: x: i32, y: i32| x + y;
```

There is nothing you can write instead of `???` above, but there is no need to because the compiler knows which type it has generated for the closure and so it can infer `f`'s type. What really *does* matter is that this anonymous type will always implement one of special traits: [`Fn`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), [`FnMut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) or [`FnOnce`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html). Consequently if you want your function to accept a closure, you need to pass it an instance of some type which implements one of these traits.

But this is natural job for generics! They are usually used when you want your function to accept some arbitrary type which implements some known trait, and situation with closures is absolutely the same. So you have this:

```
fn call_closure<F: FnMut(i64) -> bool>(f: F) -> bool {
    f(10)
}
```

Because this function argument has generic type, this function can be used with any type which implements `FnMut(i64) -> bool` trait (which is just a shorthand for `FnMut<(i64,), bool>`, including anonymous types for closures generated by the compiler:

```
call_closure(|x| x > 10);
call_closure(|x| x == 42);
```

The compiler will generate a unique type for each of these closures, but since these generated types will implement `FnMut(i64) -> bool` trait, `call_closure` will happily accept both of them.

The situation with different type parameters which I described in the beginning naturally extends to closures because the same mechanism is used here, that is, traits.

```
fn call_closures_2<F: FnMut(i64) -> bool>(f1: F, f2: F) -> bool {
    f1(10) && f2(20)
}
```

This function accepts two arguments which must be *of the same type* as long as this type implements `FnMut(i64) -> bool` trait. And this means that this invocation won't work:

```
call_closures_2(|x| x > 9, |x| x == 20)
```

It won't work because these closures have *unique*, i.e. different types, but the function requires that the types must be the same. For example, this does work:

```
fn call_closures_3<F: Fn(i64) -> bool>(f1: &F, f2: &F) -> bool {
    f1(10) && f2(20)
}

let f = |&: x: i64| x == 10;
call_closures_3(&f, &f);
```

Note that the function arguments must still be of the same type (now references for the convenience of the example), but since we call it with references to the same closure, their type *is* the same, and everything works fine. This is not very useful though because it is very limiting - usually you want to provide different closures to functions which takes several ones.

For this reason the function needs *separate* type parameters in order to accept different closures:

```
fn call_closures_4<F1, F2>(f1: F1, f2: F2) -> bool
        where F1: FnMut(i64) -> bool,
              F2: FnMut(i64) -> bool {
    f1(10) && f2(20)
}

call_closures_4(|x| x >= 9, |x| x <= 42)
```

Now type parameters are independent, and even though closures have different anonymous types, it is ok to call this function with them: `F1` will become the generated type of the first closure and `F2` will become the generated type of the second closure.

Answer (score 2):

Every single closure that is written has a unique type. The compiler basically turns it into a structure with fields to store each variable that is closed over, and implements one of the `Fn*` traits ([`Fn`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), [`FnMut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) and [`FnOnce`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html)) for it with an appropriate signature, e.g. `Fn(i64) -> bool`, a.k.a. `Fn<(i64,), bool>`.

This is why it is using the regular generic constraint syntax, because that is exactly what is going on.

Comment: In which case, both those closures clearly satisfy the type `Fn(i64) -> bool`.  Why should we create another type parameter with exactly the same constraint?  [Also addressing @DK.]  Thanks.

Comment: It is by far the simplest model to implement to produce a unique type for each closure, and given the nature of unboxed closures it is the only really sensible model. Even though it would be possible to merge *some* of them, for cases with the same signatures and captured variables and types, to do so would lead to a great deal more confusion in the significant majority of cases.

Comment: As I said, each closure is of a unique type, and each generic type binds to exactly one type, so it follows from that that if you want to pass two different closures you will need two generic parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The word "signature" implies that the two closure types are the same, but they aren't.  It's more useful to look at them as constraints.  For reference:

```
fn fizzbuzz<F1, F2>(n: i64, f: F1, fs: &str, b: F2, bs: &str)
    where F1: Fn(i64) -> bool,
          F2: Fn(i64) -> bool
```

This doesn't say "`F1` is the type `Fn(i64) -> bool`", it says: "`F1` must be a type which implements the `Fn(i64) -> bool` signature".  It's like how there are many different types which implement the `Iterator` trait, but which all implement the same interface.

In fact, things like `Fn(i64) -> bool` are actually just traits in disguise, but (if I recall correctly), the syntax for this isn't quite ready yet.  In earlier versions, you could write this as `Fn<(i64,), bool>`.

Comment: We must write `Fn(X) -> Y` rather than `Fn<(X,), Y>` (which is considered unstable, and therefore will be unusable in stable releases of Rust) because the Rust team wants to retain the option of switching `Fn` and friends to have a variable number of type parameters, in case this feature gets implemented in Rust eventually (it's not planned for 1.0, anyway).