# Rust compiler complaints about 2 almost identical closures

Tags: rust

I have this simple struct with 2 Hashsets:

```rust
pub struct IpAddresses {
    pub ipv4s: HashSet<String>,
    pub ipv6s: HashSet<String>,
}
```

and then a simple function which is supposed to provide an iterator to one of the sets:

```rust
  pub fn shared2(&self, ipv6: bool) -> impl Iterator<Item = IpAddr> + '_ {
        
       
        if ipv6 {
            self
            .ipv6s
            .iter()
            .filter_map(|a| IpAddr::from_str(a).ok())
        } else {
            self
            .ipv4s
            .iter()
            .filter_map(|a| IpAddr::from_str(a).ok())
        }
    }
```

I get the following error with the suggestion to use box:

```
error[E0308]: `if` and `else` have incompatible types
   --> src/models/ip_address.rs:131:13
    |
125 |   /         if ipv6 {
126 |   |             self
    |  _|_____________-
127 | | |             .ipv6s
128 | | |             .iter()
129 | | |             .filter_map(|a| IpAddr::from_str(a).ok())
    | |_|_____________________________________________________- expected because of this
130 |   |         } else {
131 | / |             self
132 | | |             .ipv4s
133 | | |             .iter()
134 | | |             .filter_map(|a| IpAddr::from_str(a).ok())
    | |_|_____________________________________________________^ expected closure, found a different closure
135 |   |         }
    |   |_________- `if` and `else` have incompatible types
    |
    = note: expected type `FilterMap<std::collections::hash_set::Iter<'_, _>, [closure@src/models/ip_address.rs:129:25: 129:53]>`
             found struct `FilterMap<std::collections::hash_set::Iter<'_, _>, [closure@src/models/ip_address.rs:134:25: 134:53]>`
    = note: no two closures, even if identical, have the same type
    = help: consider boxing your closure and/or using it as a trait object
help: you could change the return type to be a boxed trait object
    |
122 |     pub fn shared2(&self, ipv6: bool) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = IpAddr> + '_> {
    |                                          ~~~~~~~                             +
help: if you change the return type to expect trait objects, box the returned expressions
    |
126 ~             Box::new(self
127 |             .shared_ipv6s
128 |             .iter()
129 ~             .filter_map(|a| IpAddr::from_str(a).ok()))
130 |         } else {
131 ~             Box::new(self
```

Interestingly enough if I copy paste one of the wings into a function, the compiler works fine without any error or need for a Box:

```rust
   fn list_shared<'a>(&'a self, items: &'a HashSet<String>) -> impl Iterator<Item = IpAddr> + 'a {
        items
            .iter()
            .filter_map(|a| IpAddr::from_str(a).ok())
         
    }

pub fn shared<'a>(&'a self, ipv6: bool) -> impl Iterator<Item = IpAddr> + 'a {
       
        if ipv6 {
            self.list_shared(&self.ipv6s)
        } else {
            self.list_shared(&self.ipv4s)
        }
    }
```

As you can see this is a copy-paste of the inner block. Why is this happening? How are those 2 identical blocks not identical in the first instance but just putting them inside a function made them identical?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Types of unboxed closures being unique to each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874683/types-of-unboxed-closures-being-unique-to-each)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each closure gets its own, anonymous type. Even though the closures have the same call signature, and even if neither of them borrows anything so no lifetimes are part of the signature, these types are not the same!

Therefore, the generic `<F>` in the returned [`FilterMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.FilterMap.html) struct has a different type in each `if` branch, leading to the error message about trying to return incompatible types.

Note that `-> impl Iterator` tells the compiler that you're returning *some* type that implements `Iterator`, but it has to be statically the same type every time, determined at compile time.

When you extract the `filter_map` call to a separate function, there is only one closure, hence one type returned from *that* function. And since this is the same type for both `if` branches, the problem goes away.

It also goes away if you assign the closure to a variable, because then it's the same type in both cases as well:

```
    pub fn shared2(&self, ipv6: bool) -> impl Iterator<Item = IpAddr> + '_ {
        let from_str = |a: &String| IpAddr::from_str(a).ok();
        if ipv6 {
            self
            .ipv6s
            .iter()
            .filter_map(from_str)
        } else {
            self
            .ipv4s
            .iter()
            .filter_map(from_str)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Thomas, I have read your reply multiple times and yet I can't still get my head around it. When you say each closure gets its own anonymous type, what is that anonymous type? The return type for both wings are the same and the compiler can see that. And why does the compiler assign an anonymous type when the type is obvious? And how does putting 2 anonymous types inside 2 separate boxes makes them identical? A box of i32 is not an identical type to a box of i16.

Comment: @Reza "what is that anonymous type?" it's the type representing the closure object, each closure gets its own and since it's anoymous, there's no "what".

Comment: "The return type for both wings are the same and the compiler can see that." it's not, since each closure has its own type (and the types are not erased or unified) the adapter types are different, therefore the return types are different.

Comment: "And how does putting 2 anonymous types inside 2 separate boxes makes them identical? A box of i32 is not an identical type to a box of i16." not sure why you're mentioning boxes here (as this answer doesn't mention it), but the reason is [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/trait-object.html) and type erasure: when you convert a box or reference to a trait object, the concrete type is removed and only the trait's remains, at the possible cost of making dispatch dynamic rather than static.

Comment: @Masklinn, I mentioned Box because that is the solution that the compiler suggested. You can see that in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

`impl Iterator<Item=IpAddr>` is saying 'this function will return **a static type that is determined at runtime** that conforms to `Iterator<Item=IpAddr>`.

It is not the same as `Box<dyn Iterator<Item=IpAddr>` which means **any type** that conforms to `Iterator<Item=IpAddr>`.

The reason it dosent work is because each each one of `|a| IpAddr::from_str(a).ok())` are diffrent types that are generated by the compiler, and filter_map rerurns a struct that has the iterator of the type [FilterMap<I, F>](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.FilterMap.html), with `F` being the type of the function.

You can see the same issue if you move your closures to named functions

```
fn ipv6_iter(a: &String) -> Option<IpAddr> {
    IpAddr::from_str(a).ok()
}
fn ipv4_iter(a: &String) -> Option<IpAddr>  {
    IpAddr::from_str(a).ok()
}

impl IpAddresses {
    pub fn shared2(&self, ipv6: bool) -> impl Iterator<Item = IpAddr> + '_  {
        if ipv6 {
            self
                .ipv6s
                .iter()
                .filter_map( ipv6_iter)
        } else {
            self
                .ipv4s
                .iter()
                .filter_map( ipv4_iter)
        }
    }
}
```

In your first branch returns a `FilterMap<IpAddresses, ipv6_iter>`, but the `else` branch returns a `FilterMap<IpAddresses, ipv4_iter>`.

By moving the logic into `list_shared`, both `filter_maps` use the same anonymous function to do the mapping, therefore have the same `FilterMap` type.

Same as using the same static function in each `filter_map`

```
fn ip_iter(s: &String) -> Option<IpAddr> {
    IpAddr::from_str(s).ok()
}
impl IpAddresses {
    pub fn shared2(&self, ipv6: bool) -> impl Iterator<Item = IpAddr> + '_  {
        if ipv6 {
            self
                .ipv6s
                .iter()
                .filter_map( ip_iter)
        } else {
            self
                .ipv4s
                .iter()
                .filter_map( ip_iter)
        }
    }
}
```

So each branch returns a `FilterMap<IpAddresses, ip_iter>`, therefore `impl Iterator<Item=IpAddr>` has a single type to resolve to.