# Assigning an unboxed closure from an if statement

Tags: types, closures, rust

I'm trying to update my code for Rust 1.0.alpha, and one section I am having trouble with can be reduced to the below example. I already annotated the closure type, and switched to unboxed closures. However I can't find the correct type for fun. I tried `fun : FnMut() -> IoResult<u32>` but even though the whole point of FnMut, FnOnce, and friends is to provide traits for closures to fulfill; the compiler can't seem to match the types properly.

I've read the following:

- [Types of unboxed closures being unique to each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27874683/types-of-unboxed-closures-being-unique-to-each)
- [Error message with unboxed closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867765/error-message-with-unboxed-closures)
- http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/11/26/purging-proc/

but they don't explain clearly how to deal with this issue

```
use std::io::File;
use std::io::IoResult;
use std::io::fs::PathExtensions;
use std::iter::range_step;

fn main() {
    let path = Path::new("fid");
    let mut file = File::open(&path);
    let big = true;
    let mut v = vec![];
    let fun = if big {
        |&mut:| file.read_be_u32()
    } else {
        |&mut:| file.read_le_u32()
    };
    for _ in range_step(0u64, path.stat().unwrap().size,4u64){
        v.push(fun().unwrap());
    }
    println!("{}",v);
}
```

This gives:

```
scratch.rs:11:15: 15:6 error: if and else have incompatible types: expected `closure[scratch.rs:12:9: 12:35]`, found `closure[scratch.rs:14:9: 14:35]` (expected closure, found a different closure)
```

and using `fun : FnMut() -> IoResult<u32>` or `fun : FnMut<(),IoResult<u32>>` gives:

```
scratch.rs:12:9: 12:35 error: mismatched types: expected `core::ops::FnMut() -> core::result::Result<u32, std::io::IoError>`, found `closure[scratch.rs:12:9: 12:35]` (expected trait core::ops::FnMut, found closure)
scratch.rs:12         |&mut:| file.read_be_u32()
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
scratch.rs:14:9: 14:35 error: mismatched types: expected `core::ops::FnMut() -> core::result::Result<u32, std::io::IoError>`, found `closure[scratch.rs:14:9: 14:35]` (expected trait core::ops::FnMut, found closure)
scratch.rs:14         |&mut:| file.read_le_u32()
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you are dealing with pre-existing functions, you don’t actually need closures at all; you can work directly with the functions, like this:

```
use std::io::{File,IoResult};
use std::iter::range_step;

fn main() {
    let path = Path::new("fid");
    let mut file = File::open(&path);
    let big = true;
    let fun: fn(_) -> _ = if big {
        Reader::read_be_u32
    } else {
        Reader::read_le_u32
    };

    println!("{:?}", fun(&mut file))
}
```

(The `: fn(_) -> _` is, alas, necessary. I’m not sure whether it will become unnecessary at some point or not.)

Comment: For anyone who like me misses it the first time: as shown in the answer snippet you can pass the object a method is targeting to the method in this manner, and that's why the closure isn't necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Here's [Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27890763/234590) without `Box`:

```
use std::io::{File,IoResult};
use std::iter::range_step;

fn main() {
    let path = Path::new("fid");
    let mut file = File::open(&path);
    let big = true;
    let mut fun_be;
    let mut fun_le;
    let mut fun: &mut FnMut() -> IoResult<u32> = if big {
        fun_be = |&mut:| file.read_be_u32();
        &mut fun_be as &mut FnMut() -> _
    } else {
        fun_le = |&mut:| file.read_le_u32();
        &mut fun_le as &mut FnMut() -> _
    };

    println!("{:?}", fun())
}
```

Comment: Nice! My train of though stopped on one uninitialized variable (which obviously won't work) and refused to go further :)

Comment: Yeah, we need 2 different variables, because we have 2 closures with 2 different types! This trick can also be used with other traits in general, not just with closures.

Comment: Nice, but since I don't see any negative side effects from the boxed version, I'll stick with that.

Comment: @CamdenNarzt: this is a slightly more efficient form as it doesn’t involve a dynamic allocation. It takes a little more stack space, but avoids an allocation. When it comes to micro-optimisation, this is the place to be ☺

Answer (score 0):

Previously, closures would be automatically *boxed*, but now we have *unboxed closures*. This is a good thing from an efficiency perspective!

However, in your case, you want to have a binding that implements a trait but we don't care about the actual type of the variable. In this case, the trait is `FnMut`, and the concrete types are automatically generated types, unique to each closure. To do this, we need to have a *trait object* (like `&Trait` or `Box<Trait>`). Here's an example where we re-box the unboxed closures, creating trait objects:

```
use std::io::{File,IoResult};
use std::iter::range_step;

fn main() {
    let path = Path::new("fid");
    let mut file = File::open(&path);
    let big = true;
    let mut fun: Box<FnMut() -> IoResult<u32>> = if big {
        Box::new(|&mut:| file.read_be_u32())
    } else {
        Box::new(|&mut:| file.read_le_u32())
    };

    println!("{:?}", fun())
}
```

Comment: BTW, to lessen the boilerplate you can write `Box<FnMut() -> IoResult<u32>>` only once: `let mut fun: Box<FnMut() -> IoRsult<u32>> = ...` and then omit `as` casts.

Comment: Ideally such thing wouldn't require boxing and heap allocation. Stack-based closures would be more than enough, as old closures demonstrate it. However, I couldn't find a proper way to conditionally construct different `&mut`-based trait objects :(

Comment: @VladimirMatveev thanks! I got bit by a compiler bug before where that [caused an ICE](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20097). Maybe it's fixed now!

Comment: @VladimirMatveev I was trying the exact same thing... `file` gets borrowed multiple times.

Comment: Yeah, and if they are created in branches themselves they are destroyed too soon...